# Does Opera browser support all video formats?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I made a video player in javascript to use it for my website. All browser (I haven't checked Safari yet) except opera can play my video file!

*Now how to make it worked with Opera browser or supported with any browser?*

*I want that user can play my video on their mobile devices as well, Do I need to take any further action for that?*

.PHP:

```
<section id="videoPlayer" title="Click on the 'Play' button to play">

<video id="myMovie" width="640" height="360">
<source src="webvid.mp4">

</video>
<nav id="control_bar">

<div id="buttons">

<button type="button" id="playButton">Play</button>
</div>

<div id="defaultBar">
<div id="progressBar"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</nav>
</section>
```

.JS:

```
/* start video player*/
 function doFirst(){
barSize=407.5;
myMovie=document.getElementById('myMovie');
playButton=document.getElementById('playButton');
bar=document.getElementById('defaultBar');
progressBar=document.getElementById('progressBar');
playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
bar.addEventListener('click',clickedBar,false);
}
function playOrPause(){
if(!myMovie.paused && !myMovie.ended){
myMovie.pause();
playButton.innerHTML='Play';
window.clearInterval(updateBar);
}else{
myMovie.play();
playButton.innerHTML='Pause';
updateBar=setInterval(update,500);

}
}
function update(){
if(!myMovie.ended){
var size=parseInt(myMovie.currentTime*barSize/myMovie.duration);
progressBar.style.width=size+'px';

}else{
progressBar.style.width='0px';
playButton.innerHTML='Play';
window.clearInterval(updateBar);
}
}
function clickedBar(e){
if(!myMovie.paused &&! myMovie.ended){
var mouseX=e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft;
var newtime=mouseX*myMovie.duration/barSize;
myMovie.currentTime=newtime;
progressBar.style.width=mouseX+'px';
}
}
window.addEventListener('load', doFirst,false);

/* end video player*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Opera supports only .webm and .ogg video formats.
https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-supports-webm-video/

I'd convert your video to .ogv and .webm add their sources to support the most browsers.

```
<video id="myMovie" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="webvid.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="webvid.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="webvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <!-- else --> Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video
</video>
```

Comment: very nice info. Then what is your best suggestion for me? Should I change that into .webm or .ogg formate? I just want that my videoplayer will work in everybrowser including mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to update opeara . May be your opeara is old so can't play mp4.